# Facebook C# SDK - Server flow authentication

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-login

I am using the Facebook C# SDK installed using NuGet to allow user's to login to my site using Facebook. In all the C# SDK documentation that I've found, the access token was obtained using the JavaScript SDK. I want to do the entire authentication flow server side without using JavaScript SDK.

1. Where can I find good documentation or sample code for the steps I need to follow for complete server side authentication using the Facebook C# SDK?
2. Is there any advantage of combining C# SDK and JavaScript SDK, or is it fine to stick to server side flow only?

Answer (score 7):

Server side authentication is same as client side, you redirect user to OAuth Dialog with parameters like *RedirectUri* and you *AppId*. Then user is redirected to *RedirectUri* with parameter *code* and now you make server side request to convert code to access token, thats all.

Read Doc for Server-Side Authentication on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/

**How to exchange the *code* for a *User Access Token* with Facebook C# SDK?**

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic response = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", 
        new
        { 
            client_id = APP_ID,
            redirect_uri = "http://www.example.com/",
            client_secret = SECRET_ID,
            code = CODE
        })
//response.access_token
//response.expires
```

Answer (score 0):

var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic signedRequest = fb.ParseSignedRequest("app_secret", Request.Params["signed_request"]);

Comment: Thanks. But I was looking for a complete working sample for using Facebook C# SDK. These are some of the links I found helpful 1) http://multitiered.wordpress.com/2010/08/05/getting-started-with-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk/#comment-140    2) http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx