# How to get access token identity in asp.net webforms external login page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm using the new Microsoft identity to manage my website login and register.

I've configured the website to start using external login (Facebook).

How i can get the Access Token in the (RegisterExternalLogin) page?

``

```
        protected void Page_Load(){
        // Process the result from an auth provider in the request
        ProviderName = IdentityHelper.GetProviderNameFromRequest(Request);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProviderName))
        {
            RedirectOnFail();
            return;
        }
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var loginInfo = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo();

            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                RedirectOnFail();
                return;
            }
            var user = manager.Find(loginInfo.Login);
            if (user != null)
            {
                IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, isPersistent: false);
                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
            }
            else if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Response.Write("ok.2");
                // Apply Xsrf check when linking
                var verifiedloginInfo = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo(IdentityHelper.XsrfKey, User.Identity.GetUserId());
                if (verifiedloginInfo == null)
                {
                    RedirectOnFail();
                    return;
                }

                var result = manager.AddLogin(User.Identity.GetUserId(), verifiedloginInfo.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {

                    var accessToken = "What can i get the access token";
                    Response.Write(accessToken + "<br>");
                    var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

                    //var client = new FacebookClient();
                    dynamic me = client.Get("me");
                    string firstName = me.first_name;
                    string lastName = me.last_name;
                    Response.Write(firstName + " " + lastName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex.Message);
                }

                email.Text = loginInfo.Email;
            }
        }
    }
```

Regards,

Moayyad

Comment: What steps have you taken towards getting this to work? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: In order to get an access token from your users on a website you must use the either the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-js-sdk) or perform what is called server flow authentication. 
Server flow authentication is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12334392/1003954)